# How to add blur to transparent detailed view controller iOS7

Tags: ios, xcode5, blur

I'm developing an app in iOS7.1 with Xcode5

My app is master-detail based

What I want to achieve is to get my menú with blur effect, I have it transparent like this:

[image]

this is my code for creating my master-detail window:

```
-(void)showSplitViewControllerInView:(UIView *)view
        withDetailViewController:(id)rightViewController{

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard        = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPad" bundle: nil];

    UINavigationController  *leftNavController;
    UINavigationController  *rightNavController;

    MenuPrincipalVC  *leftViewController     = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuPrincipalVC"];
    leftViewController.title            = @" ";


    leftNavController                   = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:leftViewController];
    rightNavController                  = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rightViewController];

    leftNavController.toolbarHidden                 = FALSE;
    rightNavController.toolbarHidden                = FALSE;
    leftNavController.navigationBar.translucent     = TRUE;
    rightNavController.navigationBar.translucent    = TRUE;
    leftNavController.toolbar.translucent           = FALSE;
    rightNavController.toolbar.translucent          = TRUE;

    UISplitViewController   *splitViewController    = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    splitViewController.viewControllers             = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:leftNavController, rightNavController, nil];
    splitViewController.delegate                    = rightViewController;

    if ([splitViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setPresentsWithGesture:)]) {
        [splitViewController setPresentsWithGesture:NO];
    }

view.window.rootViewController      = splitViewController;
}
```

and for making it transparent I just set the table view of my menu with alpha to 0.98 like this:

[image]

---

**EDIT:** this question was marked as duplicated but is not the same trying to add transparency a UIView inside a view controller than a UITableView Controller as master view controller entire, I already tried the solutions suggested as answer there but I could not achieve my goal yet...

Comment: What happened with each of the blur effect changes you tried?

Comment: The question is not clear? Where is the problem? The transparency or that you cannot achieve the overlapping?

Comment: when I use those frameworks they work fine in a view controller with a UIView I want to get blur, but in a master-detail view controller, the master view (menu) is different, it appears over my detail view controller, I want to make my entire master view with blur and transparency, but all I get is a transparent view controller in blue color with no blur